# Using apply in a 'window'

Tags: r, apply

Is there a way to use apply functions on 'windows' or 'ranges'? This example should serve to illustrate:

```
a <- 11:20
```

Now I want to calculate the sums of consecutive elements. i.e.

[11+12, 12+13, 13+14, ...]

The ways I can think of handling this are:

```
a <- 11:20
b <- NULL
for(i in 1:(length(a)-1))
{
    b <- c(b, a[i] + a[i+1])
}
# b is 23 25 27 29 31 33 35 37 39
```

or alternatively,

```
d <- sapply( 1:(length(a)-1) , function(i) a[i] + a[i+1] )
# d is 23 25 27 29 31 33 35 37 39
```

Is there a better way to do this?
I'm hoping there's something like:

```
e <- windowapply( a, window=2, function(x) sum(x) )  # fictional function
# e should be 23 25 27 29 31 33 35 37 39
```

Comment: See, for example: `library(RcppRoll) ; roll_sum(a, 2)`. `library(zoo) ; rollsum(a, 2)`. There is, also, a `rollapply` in "zoo" for custom functions. "RcppRoll" is faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an anternative using `rollapply` from zoo package

```
> rollapply(a, width=2, FUN=sum )
[1] 23 25 27 29 31 33 35 37 39
```

zoo package also offers `rollsum` function

```
> rollsum(a, 2)
[1] 23 25 27 29 31 33 35 37 39
```

Answer (score 4):

We can define a general moving() function:

```
moving <- function(f){
  g <- function(i , x, n , f, ...) f(x[(i-n+1):i], ...)
  function(x, n, ...) {
    N <- length(x)
    vapply(n:N, g, x , n , f, FUN.VALUE = numeric(1), ...)
  }  
}
```

Function moving() returns function  that, in turn can be used to generate any moving_f() functions:

```
moving_sum <- moving(sum)  
moving_sum(x = 11:20, n = 2)
```

similarly, even passing extra arguments to moving_f()

```
moving_mean <- moving(mean)  
moving_mean(x = rpois(22, 6), n = 5, trim = 0.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your `windowapply` function by first creating a list of indices and then `*apply`ing over them such that they are used as extraction indices:

```
j <- lapply(seq_along(a), function(i) if(i<10) c(i,i+1) else i)
sapply(j, function(j) sum(a[j]))
## [1] 23 25 27 29 31 33 35 37 39
```

Comment: Neat! Slightly hard to generalize to windows of arbitrary sizes, though.